# What's in gradle a group, module and artifact?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, xstream, xmlpullparser

*The gradle docs don't take the time to explain the entities they are dealing with. That's why I want to ask such a basic question.*

I've got a to understand in detail, what the terms **group, module and artifact** really mean to alter this code:

```
compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
}
```

About a year ago I used that exclude statement I took from [Android dalvik conversion for xmlpullparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146142/android-dalvik-conversion-for-xmlpullparser/31631112#31631112) to fix a Multiple dex files failure.

However, after upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 that error occurrs again! Now it says: `Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/mxp1/MXParser` and sometimes `...XmlPullParserException.java` So, id like to understand how the parameters I give `exclude` must be shaped.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html) one could think a **group is the package name and the artifact is the class**:

```
//excluding a particular transitive dependency:
exclude module: 'cglib' //by artifact name
exclude group: 'org.jmock' //by group
exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'iAmBuggy' //by both name and group
```

Another [chinese page](http://blog.csdn.net/bdhk6688/article/details/77963758) ([translated](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.csdn.net%2Fbdhk6688%2Farticle%2Fdetails%2F77963758&edit-text=)) used those excludes

```
 compile ( 'com.thoughtworks.xstream: xstream: 1.4.7' ) {
       exclude group : 'xmlpull' 
       exclude group : 'XmlPullParser' 
 }
```

Built on that findings wonder

- how `xmlpull` worked when the package name begins with `org.xmlpull`?
- what projects those terms refer to in my scenario. Where was the group name defined?
- What kinda group is `XmlPullParser`?
- Must I clean, rebuild or just build the project after altering those parameters? Because sometimes it complains about different files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group, artifact and version are chosen semi randomly and do NOT need to match packages or classes in the jar file.

For example [commons-lang](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22commons-lang%22%20AND%20a%3A%22commons-lang%22) has `groupId = 'commons-lang'` but the classes are in `org.apache.commons.lang.*` package

The group, artifact and version are defined within the build file of the project. In maven this will be in `pom.xml` in gradle this will be in `build.gradle` (and `settings.gradle`)

If you want to know the group, artifact, version for a project (aka GAV, aka maven co-ordinates) you will usually go to the project's home page.

You can also use the [maven central advanced search](https://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav) to "fuzzy" search eg by artifactId or by a classname within a jar. If you are using an in-house repository you can likely "fuzzy" search via the web interface there also